# JAVA - class and it's object, super

Tags: java, user-interface, object, interface

This is the class Gui.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Gui extends JFrame{
    Principal obiect;
    public JButton heads = new JButton("Heads");
    public JButton tails = new JButton("Tails");
    public static JTextField display;
    public JTextField comboul;
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public int predictie;


    public Gui(){
        super("HeadsOrTails");
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(100, 100));
        panel.add(heads,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        panel.add(tails,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        panel.add(display,BorderLayout.CENTER); //HERE IS ERROR
        panel.add(comboul,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }


    public void dacaHeads(){
        if(heads.getModel().isPressed()) predictie = 0;
    }
    public void dacaTails(){
        if(tails.getModel().isPressed()) predictie = 1;



        heads.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               dacaHeads();
               obiect.flip();

               if(predictie == obiect.returnStatus() ){
                   String s = comboul.getText();
                   int combo = Integer.valueOf(s);
                   s = Integer.toString(++combo);
                   comboul.setText(s);}
                   else{
                       String z = "0";
                       comboul.setText(z);
                   }
            }
        });
        tails.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                dacaTails();
                obiect.flip();
                if(predictie == obiect.returnStatus() ){
                    String s = comboul.getText();
                    int combo = Integer.valueOf(s);
                    s = Integer.toString(++combo);
                    comboul.setText(s);}
                else{
                        String z = "0";
                comboul.setText(z);
            }
        }
        });



    }}
```

This is class Principal.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
    public class Principal extends Gui {
    public int combo;
    public static Random bulion = new Random();
    public static boolean sansa;
    public static boolean input;
    public int status;

    //STATUS 0 = HEADS;
    //STATUS 1 = TAILS;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Gui lee = new Gui(); //HERE IS ERROR
            Principal obiect = new Principal();
            lee.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            lee.setSize(500,500);
            lee.setVisible(true);
        }

        public int flip(){
        boolean sansa2 ;
        sansa2 = bulion.nextBoolean();
        if(sansa2){
           status = 0;
            display.setText("Heads");
        }
        else{
            status = 1;
            display.setText("Tails");
        }
        return status;

    }

     public int returnStatus(){
         return status;
     }
}
```

These are the errors : 
    FIXED:
    //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    //at Gui.(Gui.java:19) // Super
    //at Principal.(Principal.java:3) //public class Principal extends Gui 
    //at Gui.(Gui.java:9) //Principal obiect = new Principal()

```
NOW:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:23)
at Principal.main(Principal.java:14)
```

It's my first post so i am sorry if you don't understand.I'll post more information if you need.

Comment: The problems up there were fixed, but now when i open it is completly white.

Answer (score 5):

When you create a `Gui` instance, it creates a `Principal` instance (since the `Gui` class has a `Prinicipal` instance variable - `Principal obiect = new Principal();`) which is also a `Gui` instance, so you get an infinite chain of constructor calls, leading to `StackOverflowError`.

To avoid it change

```
Principal obiect = new Principal();
```

to

```
Principal obiect;
```

and initialize this instance after the `Gui` instance is created (i.e. after the call to `Gui lee = new Gui();` in your main method).

For example, add to `Gui` class :

```
public void setPrincipal (Principal object)
{
    this.object = object;
}
```

And in your main :

```
Gui lee = new Gui();
lee.setPrincipal (new Principal());
```

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that.Now i think i understood what StackOverflowError is.

Comment: But now i have these errors: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException .at Gui.<init>(Gui.java:23)
 at Principal.main(Principal.java:14).

Comment: Here is first error : panel.add(display,BorderLayout.CENTER); .                     And the second error:Gui lee = new Gui();.

Comment: @AlexSS Actually it's something else - you don't initialize this variable - `public static JTextField display;`

Comment: I initialiazed JTextField display and JTextField comboul too. Now it's running. but the window is completely white.